# Let $Y$ a uniform random variable in $[0,1]$, and let $X$ a uniform variable in $[1,e^Y]$

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ a  uniform random variable in $[0,1]$, and let $X$ a uniform variable in $[1,e^Y]$

Find $E[X]$

**My work**

As $Y$ is uniform random variable in $[0,1]$ then

$$\Pr[Y \le y] = \begin{cases} 0, & y \le 0 \\ y, & 0 < y \le 1, \\ 1, & 1 < y. \end{cases}$$

As $X$ is a uniform random variable in $[0,e^Y]$ then

$$\Pr[X \le x] = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0, \\ x, & 0 < x, \le e^Y \\ 1, & 1 < e^Y. \end{cases}$$

I'm little stuck trying to finding $E[X]$

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You say $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[1,e^{Y}]$ in the title and $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,e^{Y}]$ in your solution.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\operatorname E(X) = \operatorname E(\operatorname E(X\mid Y)) = \operatorname E\left( \frac{1+e^Y} 2 \right) = \int_0^1 \frac {1+e^y} 2 \cdot (1 \, dy) = \cdots
$$

Comment: Thanks Michael. One question, why you say $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$? i don't see that step.

Comment: @Bvss12 [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: Oh, thanks for all

Comment: Michael sorry for ask, but i'm having serious problem trying to prove $E(X|Y)=\frac{1+e^y}{2}$ can you help me with that?

Comment: @Bvss12 $X\mid Y\sim\mathcal U[1;e^Y]$, so $\mathsf E(X\mid Y) =\tfrac{1}{2}(1+e^Y)$ since the expectation of a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[a;b]$ is $\tfrac 12(a+b)$.

Comment: @Bvss12 : If $X$ is uniformly distributed on an interval $[a,b]$ then $$ \operatorname E(X) = \int_a^b x \, \frac{dx}{b-a} = \frac{a+b} 2. $$

Answer (score 0):

You should write $P\{X \leq x \mid Y\}=  0$ for  $x\leq 1 $,  $x$ for   $1<x\leq e^Y$  $1$ for  $ x>e^Y $ since $X$ is uniform on $[1,Y]$ not $[0,Y]$. Now you have to take expectation to get $P\{X\leq x\}$. You will get $xP\{Y \geq \ln x\}+P\{Y< \ln x\}$. Can you compute this now?